# How can one draw thumbnails as children in D3 Zoomable Icicle Layout?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to use the D3 Zoomable Icicle example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873) to view a file hierarchy.

I would like to have thumbnails to visualize the "leaf nodes" or "files".

[image: Required Customization]

I am not sure if this is possible using the example, and then if it is, how to go about having a different visualization of the folders and files within this layout? I have no idea how to attempt this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you implement your nodes as `<g>` elements, then you can use an `.each()` call to add either a rectangle or an `<image>` element and set it's size based on the data.

However, if you have lots of leaf nodes in a partition layout, the partitions tend to end up quite narrow, so the size of your image might be uselessly small.  I see from your mock-up that you're hoping to tile the thumbnails in a multi-line grid.  You're going to need to create some custom layout code, that identifies all the files (leaf nodes) within a given parent folder and calculates the amount of horizontal space which they collectively take up, then assigns the thumbnail positions into a grid no wider than that space.

You'll also need to make sure that your partition layout is sorting the partitions so that all the leaves are together, separate from any subfolders.  I think the default sort should work this way, but it's something to keep in mind.

To make your updating and layout code straightforward, once you calculate the new positions for these leaves, make sure you save the `x`,`y`, `dx` (width) and `dy` (height) values in their respective data objects, over-writing the position and size created by the partition layout.

Comment: Thanks so much Amelia! So can I still use the partition layout when creating a custom layout? I'm not even sure how to create a custom layout...

Comment: Oh, I wasn't suggesting you start for scratch.  Run your nodes through the partition layout so that get their initial positions, but then you'll have to do some extra work on the leaf nodes.  I'd suggest taking the nodes array from the partition function, using a filter to find the leaf nodes (children array is null), and then using a nest function to group the leaf nodes according to their parent node.  Then for each parent in the nested array, scan through  the sub-array of leaf nodes, find the max and min x values to calculate how much space you have, and assign new positions to each leaf.

Comment: Hi @AmeliaBR, this works a treat! Thank you so much! I just need to update the labels positions according to the position of the thumbnails, and then also deal with narrow parents - if you have any ideas on this please let me know it would be much appreciated. I am thinking of resizing the image based on the available space?

Comment: Resizing shouldn't be a problem -- just set the width using `Math.min(imageWidth, parent.dx)` and it will scale to be no wider than the available space.  I'm not sure how positioning labels would be any different from positioning images.

Comment: That worked thanks, I also used it to resize the thumbnails for wide folders.